# Specify the return type of an arrow function in an interface declaration

Tags: typescript

I want to tell typescript that I'll be using **an interface that offers a function named "foo" that always returns a string.** The body of the function will be defined by the object implementing the interface.

Something like this :

```
export interface IMyInterface {
   foo: ():string => void;
}
```

Unfortunately the compiler says that this `:string` shouldn't be there.
What's the correct syntax? If I remove `:string` then the function returns type "any" and I don't want to allow that.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions

Comment: In your example, what did you think `void` stood for?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value on the RHS of the arrow is the return type. You're currently saying it is `void`.

You can also use the alternative syntax (`bar` below) where the "is a function" status is declared in the name.

```
interface Example {
    foo: () => string;
    bar(): string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of the arrow function comes after `=>`.

```
export interface IMyInterface {
   foo: () => string;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFkBPfFNLXOAbwFgAoOJ9CCALjgAoBKOAXgB8cAM4woyAOYBuBgF8gA)